# cakePHP get data from hasMany assocation version 2.1

Tags: cakephp, join, model

My model1 hasMany model2, I need to do the condition statement on the model2 so in other words:

```
 $result = $this->Model1->find("all",array("conditions" => array("Model2"."field" => $outsideValue)));
```

I am however getting a unknown column Model2.field which looks due to Model1 not including Model2 as a join. How do I do cakePHP joins with a hasMany?

Comment: You have `"Model2"."field"`, when you should have `"Model2.field"`. I don't know if it is a typo in the question, or an error in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

> $result= $this->Model1->find('all',array('recursive'=>1,"conditions"
>   => array("Model2"."field" => $outsideValue)));

or:

> $result= $this->Model1->find('all',array("contains"
>   => array("Model2"=>array('conditions'=>array("field" => $outsideValue))));

The first one will give you all model 1 elements which are linked to a Model 2 verifying the condition.

The second one will you all Model 1 elements, with  only the associated Model2 verifying the condition.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use [ad-hoc joins](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/quick-tip-doing-ad-hoc-joins-in-model-find) or the [linkable behavior](https://github.com/Terr/linkable/wiki) to get the joins.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$this->Model1->bindModel(array(
    'hasMany' => array(
        'Model2' => array('conditions'=>array('Model2.field'=>$outsidevalue))
)));
$data = $this->Model1->find('all');
```